# How to encrypt and decrypt the password in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server

How to encrypt and decrypt the password in SQL Server 2008 R2? Please describe all the process in steps using hash bytes function and salt value?

Comment: Do you mean the encrypt and decrypt SQL server password or password entries in the database?

Comment: Yeah, with all the steps.

Comment: Hashing is not encryption, the first is one-way, the second reversible with a key.

Comment: @SiddharthaGoswami When you are asked an either-or question, "Yes" is a meaningless answer ... Which ***one*** gets the "Yes"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.[User]
    (
        UserID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        LoginName NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
        PasswordHash BINARY(64) NOT NULL,
        Salt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
        FirstName NVARCHAR(40) NULL,
        LastName NVARCHAR(40) NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_User_UserID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserID ASC)
    )

    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspAddUser
        @pLogin NVARCHAR(50), 
        @pPassword NVARCHAR(50),
        @pFirstName NVARCHAR(40) = NULL, 
        @pLastName NVARCHAR(40) = NULL,
        @responseMessage NVARCHAR(250) OUTPUT
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON

        DECLARE @salt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER=NEWID()
        BEGIN TRY

            INSERT INTO dbo.[User] (LoginName, PasswordHash, Salt, FirstName, LastName)
            VALUES(@pLogin, HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @pPassword+CAST(@salt AS NVARCHAR(36))), @salt, @pFirstName, @pLastName)

           SET @responseMessage='Success'

        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SET @responseMessage=ERROR_MESSAGE() 
        END CATCH
    END

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspLogin
    @pLoginName NVARCHAR(254),
    @pPassword NVARCHAR(50),
    @responseMessage NVARCHAR(250)='' OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @userID INT

    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 UserID FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE LoginName=@pLoginName)
    BEGIN
        SET @userID=(SELECT UserID FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE LoginName=@pLoginName AND PasswordHash=HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @pPassword+CAST(Salt AS NVARCHAR(36))))

       IF(@userID IS NULL)
           SET @responseMessage='Incorrect password'
       ELSE 
           SET @responseMessage='User successfully logged in'
    END
    ELSE
       SET @responseMessage='Invalid login'

END
```

Comment: Just using a hash is insecure, it allows rainbow table attacks. Appending a salt and password and hashing is not as secure as an HMAC. Using an HMAC is a step in the right direction but still not current best practice. The password should be run through an HMAC with a seed multiple times, use a function such as Crypt, password_hash or PBKDF2.

Answer (score 0):

Do not save passwords in the data base either in plain text or encrypted. Not even hashes such as MD5 or up to SHA-512. If it is not salted and iterated it is not sufficient.

Store salted, iterated HMACs of the passwords. Use a function such as Bcrypt, password_hash, PBKDF2 or similar.

Comment: but these function are used in java, how can I implement in c#? can you give an example using one of above function in c#, that will be beneficial to me?